# When is 'focus' called in 'autocomplete'

Tags: javascript, jquery

The 'focus' documentation from http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ states :

> focusType:autocompletefocus Before focus is moved to an item (not
>   selecting), ui.item refers to the focused item. The default action of
>   focus is to replace the text field's value with the value of the
>   focused item, though only if the focus event was triggered by a
>   keyboard interaction. Canceling this event prevents the value from
>   being updated, but does not prevent the menu item from being focused.
>
> Code examples
>
> Supply a callback function to handle the focus event as an init
>   option. $( ".selector" ).autocomplete({    focus: function(event, ui)
>   { ... } }); Bind to the focus event by type: autocompletefocus. $(
>   ".selector" ).bind( "autocompletefocus", function(event, ui) {   ...
>   });

Using below code sets an attribute called 'mytag' with value 'tester' on all of the autocomplete elements even though I have not selected the elements. Why is the attribute 'focus' not added just when one of the drop downs is focused, instead of being added when page is loaded ?

```
 $("#myDiv").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        $(".ui-autocomplete li").attr("mytag", "tester");
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When hovering over a suggested completion with your mouse or selecting one with arrow keys. It's a normal "focus", applied on the autocomplete box.
Try it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/qk9gv/!

Answer (score 0):

when the input the autocomplete is attached to becomes "focused".. 
i.e. the moment you can start typing.